# Sticky header jumps during scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a problem that still could not solve any questions already made in Stack.

I have a sticky header that makes a jump when I move and I can not find a solution.

I leave the code:

**HTML**

```
<header class="container-fluid" id="myHeader">

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row" id="encabezado">

        <!--Here is a button that makes SlideToggle and shows content. Important to know so that elements do not overlap when you scroll and click on the button-->

        </div>

    </div>

</header>
```

**JS:**

```
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction 
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

// Get the header
var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");

// Get the offset position of the navbar
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

// Add the sticky class to the header when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.sticky {

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px #222;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px #222;
    box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px #222;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;

}
```

Comment: Can you create a working snippet from your code?

Comment: If you were to fix it in-place from the start, and just add the shadow when you scroll past its height, you won't have to worry about content shifting. If you have another reason to change from dynamic to fixed positioning, though, this won't help. http://jsfiddle.net/dcr2mpu1/

Answer (score 0):

The logic is simple, when your nav turns 'fixed', its height is subtracted from the height of your main container, causing a reduction in size.

For example, let us say your navbar is 100px tall.
If your navbar gets the class .sticky, your 'content' loses that 100px, causing the jump that you feel.

In order to avoid this, you need to, at the same time that you give the nav the class sticky, you must give your content area a class with padding-top:100px, for example, so the amount of space 'taken away' is returned and thus no perceivable jump is felt.

After that, to make the transition more smooth, you need to time your adding of the class sticky to the precise offset where there navbar meets the content.

UPDATE: CODE SAMPLE

By the info you provide, which is a partial sample of your code, it is not clear what element you use for the rest of your content (not counting header), I will assume this element is a  with class="content" and id="myContent"

CSS

```
.content.top-padding { padding-top: 100px; }
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction 
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

// Get the header
var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");

// Get the content area
var content = document.getElementById("myContent");

// Get the offset position of the navbar
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

// Add the sticky class to the header when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    // here you add sticky -> also add top padding
    header.classList.add("sticky");
    header.classList.add("top-padding");
  } else {
    // here you remove sticky -> also remove top padding
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
    header.classList.remove("top-padding");
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool! I did not know that. Could you give me an example of how I should do it with my code in mind? Since I would not know how to do the last thing you name.

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much for your time

Comment: Do you know how to measure/calculate the height of your navbar?

Comment: No, do not do that. Now I'm testing the example you gave me

Comment: I have tried your example applied in my code, but it still does not work :(

Comment: Do you having a working online version of your site we can take a look at? the 100px example I gave, as well as the imaginary content name, are merely suppositions. I need to see the full structure of your site as well as calculate the real height of your header

Comment: Now I will make an example in jsfiddle so that it sees all the code, beyond that it does not work for parts of php

Comment: Ok, if you make a js fiddle with all the relevant code, we can troubleshoot it quickly

Comment: Surely find names in Spanish. My project is in Spanish, that's why

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution?

Comment: Spanish is fine, but, the problem is in your fiddle example - even when I get rid of the php tags, the content is almost 0, so the page doesn't have anywhere to scroll, and thus, there is not much testing to be done. I will upload and example later tonight.

Comment: Sorry for my example that brought you confusions. I look forward to your example!

Comment: Actually, have you tried something like this?:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_navbar_sticky

Comment: Damian, did you get a chance to look at the link provided?